# Bad flag delimiters .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im testing out URL rewritting but Im having issues with htacces. I have

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} != d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} != f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} != l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and my vhost looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@sitename.com
        ServerName www.mvc.com
        ServerAlias my.mvc

        DocumentRoot /home/user/Documents/MyMVC

        <Directory /home/user/Documents/MyMVC>
            Require all granted
            AllowOverride all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /home/user/SiteLogs/mvc/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

With this settings Im getting `/home/user/Documents/MyMVC/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters` Im not sure what am I missing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!=` is not a valid option in RewriteConds: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                                 ^--- "dash", not "equals"
```

Answer (score 1):

The Rewrite Conditions are flags not "!="
Should look something like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```